# Prevent click event in one function from affecting click event on another function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I am implementing click events on accordions. An accordion has a link and a help image. When a user clicks the link, it should expand the accordion only. When a user clicks on the help image, it should display a tooltip help message without expanding the accordion.

The click event on the link works very well on first click when i load the page. The problem arises when i load the page and then click the help image.It displays only the help message without expanding the accordion, but now when a user clicks the label of the accordion to expand it, it won't fire unless the user clicks two times.

[image: Screen capture of the accordions]

When a user clicks on General or Contact, it should expand the respective accordions(this functions well). When a user clicks the image on the right, it should load a help tooltip without expanding the accordion(this functions well too, but when a user clicks the help image and then clicks General or Contact, the respective accordion will load only after two clicks.) I want to make it to load after only one click.

This is my asp.net code:

```
<ul>
<li id="function_contents_0" runat="server">
   <a href="javascript:;" id="function_0" class="accordion_functions_inactive" style="height:16px; width:95%;">
   <asp:Label ID="Label_Company_General" runat="server" Text="General" style="float: left;">
   </asp:Label>
   <span style="float: right; text-align: right; background-image:url('../assets/images/help.png'); width:16px; height:16px;" class="tooltip" title="This is help">
   </span>
   </a>
   <div class="function_contents" id="content_function_0">
   //some more code here
   </div>
</li>

<li id="function_contents_1" runat="server">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="function_1" class="accordion_functions_inactive" style="height:16px; width:95%;">
    <asp:Label ID="Label_Company_Contact" runat="server" Text="Contact" style="float: left;">
    </asp:Label> 
    <span style="float: right; text-align: right; background-image:url('../assets/images/help.png'); width:16px; height:16px;" class="tooltip" title="Am a second help">
    </span>               
    </a>
    <div class="function_contents" id="content_function_1">
    //some more code here
 </li>

 //The third accordion goes in here

</ul>
```

The javascript code:

```
//code for expanding accordions

 $("#accordion_functions a").on('click', function () {
    var this_prop = $(this).prop('class');
    var levels;

    if ($(this).attr('id') != undefined) {
        levels = $(this).attr('id').split('_')
    }

    if (this_prop == 'accordion_functions_active') {
        $('#content_function_' + levels[1]).hide();          
        $(this).prop('class', 'accordion_functions_inactive');
    }

    if (this_prop == 'accordion_functions_inactive') {
        $('#content_function_' + levels[1]).show();
        $(this).prop('class', 'accordion_functions_active');
    }

});

//code for showing the tooltip help message

$('#accordion_functions ul li a span:nth-child(2).tooltip').on('click', function () {
    var levels;
    var this_prop = $('#accordion_functions ul li a').prop('class');

    if ($('#accordion_functions ul li a').attr('id') != undefined) {
        levels = $('#accordion_functions ul li a').attr('id').split('_')
    }

    $('#content_function_' + levels[1]).hide();
    $('#accordion_functions ul li a').prop('class', 'accordion_functions_active');
    $('.accordion_functions_active').css('backgroundPosition', '5px -8px');

});
```

This is my css:

```
.accordion_functions_inactive {
background-image: url(../images/arrows_white_blue.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 5px -8px;
}
.accordion_functions_active {
background-image: url(../images/arrows_white_blue.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 5px 9px;
}
```

What could i be doing wrong? My goal is when a user clicks the help message image and clicks it again to close, it doesn't affect the accordion click (the accordion expand event will fire after one click but not two clicks).

I have read about the use of `unbind()` , `return false`, `die()`, `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` but they have not helped solve my issue.
Any suggestion?

**EDIT: Added a screen shot of the accordions and more explanation.**

Comment: can u create a fiddle, so that it will be easy to understand and rectify your issue

Comment: @dreamweiver It will be hard since there is no fiddle for asp.net

Comment: You dont have to place asp.net there, it wont support. better add the html rendered code  to fiddle with your js code.

Comment: Okay, i have edited the question and added a screen shot of the accordion. Please see if you can understand it.

Comment: I have understood your problem bro, if i have to know what is causing this, then you have add a fiddle for this, else its difficult to know the actually reason for your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, here is what's happening:

When you click on the help button, it executes this line:

```
$('#accordion_functions ul li a').prop('class', 'accordion_functions_active');
```

which adds the `accordion_functions_active` class to **all** of your accordian links.

There is no corresponding instruction to show the accordion content, so the content and link class are out of sync. ie. The class is set to active, but the content is still hidden. This is why it takes two clicks to show the content.

The first click hides the already hidden content, based on the active class, and sets the class to inactive. The class and content hide/show state are now synchronized, and it will behave normally on the second click.

So either change this to

```
$('#accordion_functions ul li a').prop('class', 'accordion_functions_inactive');
$('.function_contents').hide();
```

Or just don't change the link class or hide the content

Comment: Exactly that is what happens and i think that is where my problem arises. I have an idea on what i should do - I should apply the prop property to the current accordion only using the 'this' keyword, but how do i do that since it is not the referenced element in the function?

Comment: If you want all accordions closed when you click on help, just ... close them all, in the way I indicated above. If you want to process that particular accordian in some special way, you can say `var link = $(this).closest('a');` ... this returns the first `a` ancestor of the help button